# rsync using shopt globstar and **/. - how to exclude directories?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu-12.04, rsync

I'm attempting to sync all files from within a large directory structure into a single root directory (ie not creating the sub directories but still including all recursive files).

Environment:

- Ubuntu 12.04 x86
- RSYNC version 3.0.9
- GNU bash version 4.2.25(1)

So far I have this command called from a bash script which works fine and provides the basic core functionality required:

```
shopt -s globstar
rsync -adv /path/to/source/**/. /path/to/dest/. --exclude-from=/myexcludefile
```

The contents of `myexcludefile` are:

```
filename
*/ 
# the */ prevents all of the directories appearing in /path/to/dest/

# other failed attempts have included:
directory1
directory1/
directory1/*
```

I now need to exclude files that are located inside certain directories in the source tree. However due to the globstar approach of looking in all directories rsync is unable to match directories to exclude. In other words, with the exception of my `/*` and `filename` rules, everything else is completely ignored.

So I'm looking for some assistance on either the excludes syntax or if there's another way of achieving the rsync of many directories into a single destination directory that doesn't use my globstar approach.

Any help or advice would be very gratefully received.

Comment: But wouldn't `/path/to/source/**/.` always match a directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to exclude directories from a globstar match, you can save those to an array, then filter the contents of that array based on a file.

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s globstar

declare -A X
readarray -t XLIST < exclude_file.txt
for A in "${XLIST[@]}"; do
    X[$A]=.
done

DIRS=(/path/to/source/**/.)
for I in "${!DIRS[@]}"; do
    D=${DIRS[I]}
    [[ -n ${X[$D]} ]] && unset 'DIRS[I]'
done

rsync -adv "${DIRS[@]}" /path/to/dest/.
```

Run with:

```
bash script.sh
```

Note that values in exclude_file.txt should really match expanded values in `/path/to/source/**/.`.

Comment: Thanks for this, whilst I've not tested the script it looks to make perfect sense and has been added to my inventory for future use.

Comment: For anyone else interested, I instead ran 2 rsync jobs - 1 to grab a list of dirs, which I then looped through to test my excluded dirs against before running the actual sync'ing rsync job on any that weren't in my exclude list.